# REST urls returning error or failed to connect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, google-app-engine, mongoose

I am trying to get data from a MongoDB Atlas cluster. This works fine on localhost, however when tried on google cloud, the URLs sent to get products for example fails.

Here is how the URLs are formatted:

```
import {DataTypes} from "./Types";

const protocol = "https";
// const hostname = "localhost"; <- this here works on localhost
const hostname = "ugo-dapashirts.appspot.com";
const port = process.env.PORT || 9090;

export const RestUrls = {
    [DataTypes.PRODUCTS]: `${protocol}://${hostname}:${port}/products`,
    [DataTypes.CATEGORIES]: `${protocol}://${hostname}:${port}/categories`,
    [DataTypes.ORDERS]: `${protocol}://${hostname}:${port}/orders`
}
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 9090

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Configuring the database
const dbConfig = require('./config/database.config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
});

// Require routes
require('./routes/department.routes.js')(app);
require('./routes/category.routes.js')(app);
require('./routes/product.routes.js')(app);
require('./routes/order.routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 9090");
});
```

Here is a sample route file:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    const products = require('../controllers/product.controllers.js');

    // Create a new product
    app.post('/api/products', products.create);

    // Retrieve all products
    app.get('/api/products', products.findAll);

    // Retrieve a single product with productId
    app.get('/api/products/:productId', products.findOne);

    // Retrieve a products with categoryId
    app.get('/api/products/:categoryId', products.findWithCategoryId);

    // Update a product with productId
    app.put('/api/products/:productId', products.update);

    // Delete a produt with productId
    app.delete('/api/products/:productId', products.delete);
}
```

And a sample controller file:

```
const Product = require('../models/product.model.js');

// Create and Save a new Product
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Validate request
    if (!req.body.categoryId) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: "categoryId cannot be empty"
        });
    }
    else if (!req.body.name) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: "Product name cannot be empty"
        });
    }
    else if (!req.body.description) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: "Product description cannot be empty"
        });
    }

    // Create a Product
    const product = new Product({
        category_id: req.body.categoryId,
        name: req.body.name, 
        description: req.body.description,
        price: Number(req.body.price).toFixed(2),
        discounted_price: Number(req.body.discountedPrice).toFixed(2),
        image: req.body.image,
        image_2: req.body.image_2,
        thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail,
        display: Number(req.body.display)
    });

    // Save Product in the database
    product.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            error: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Product."
        });
    });
};

// Retrieve and return all products from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Product.find()
    .then(product => {
        res.send(product);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            error: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving products."
        });
    });
};

// Find a single product with a productId
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    Product.findById(req.params.productId)
    .then(product => {
        if(!product) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });            
        }
        res.send(product);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            error: "Error retrieving product with id " + req.params.productId
        });
    });
};

// find product with categoryId
exports.findWithCategoryId =(req, res) => {
    Product.find({category_id: req.params.categoryId})
    .then(product => {
        if(product.length) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with categoryId " + req.params.categoryId
            });            
        }
        res.send(product);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with categoryId " + req.params.categoryId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            error: "Error retrieving product with categoryId " + req.params.categoryId
        });
    });
};

// Update a product identified by the productId in the request
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    // Validate Request
    if (!req.body.categoryId) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: "categoryId cannot be empty"
        });
    }
    else if(!req.body.name) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: "Product name cannot be empty"
        });
    }
    else if (!req.body.description) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: "Product description cannot be empty"
        });
    }

    // Find Product and update it with the request body
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.productId, {
        category_id: req.body.categoryId,
        name: req.body.name, 
        description: req.body.description,
        price: Number(req.body.price).toFixed(2),
        discounted_price: Number(req.body.discountedPrice).toFixed(2),
        image: req.body.image,
        image_2: req.body.image_2,
        thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail,
        display: Number(req.body.display)
    }, {new: true})
    .then(prod => {
        if(!prod) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });
        }
        res.send(prod);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            error: "Error updating product with id " + req.params.productId
        });
    });
};

// Delete a product with the specified productId in the request
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.productId)
    .then(prod => {
        if(!prod) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });
        }
        res.send({message: "Product deleted successfully!"});
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId' || err.name === 'NotFound') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: "Product not found with id " + req.params.productId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            error: "Could not delete product with id " + req.params.productId
        });
    });
};
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
handlers: 
- url: /api/.*
  script: auto
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\..+)$
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

Is it an issue with the ports? I am really confused, GCP sometimes sucks

Comment: If the issue only occurs in the deployed environment, the cause is unlikely to be in your code. Can you include your `app.yaml` file? Also do you see any log messages from your server when deployed (to check if the request even makes it to your application)?

Comment: @HenryWoodyJust added the app.yaml file

Comment: Did you check the logs for the server?

Comment: Also what have you set the value of `PORT` to in production?

Comment: @HenryWoody the logs of the server do not really explain much. The value of PORT is 9090

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements) on the GAE `app.yaml` configuration for Node.js, your server must accept requests on port 8080 (yours is set to 9090).

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> **entrypoint** | Optional. Overrides the default startup behavior by executing the **entrypoint** command when your app starts. For your app to receive HTTP requests, the **entrypoint** element should contain a command which starts a web server that *listens on port 8080*. If you do not specify an entrypoint, App Engine uses the start script specified in your **package.json** file.

Comment: Sorry mate I get error: GET https://ugo-dapashirts.appspot.com:8080/products net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: the requests should go to port 80, but internally the server should be running on 8080 I believe

Comment: Hi man, I am getting the HTML document back instead of JSON. Very tiring

Comment: Oh looks like that would be from your `handlers` in `app.yaml`, that one that sends `index.html` gets anything that doesn't contain a "." character in it. What will help with avoiding frontend/backend route conflicts is prefixing your server-side routes with `/api` so you could change to `/api/products`, that way if you have a page on your frontend for products you won't get a conflict. Then update `handlers` so that `index.html` is only sent for routes that do not start with `/api`

Comment: Now getting an internal server error (500), I have edited my question to include the modified app.yaml

Comment: yes I did, tested it on localhost and works seamlessly but not on GCP

Comment: Hmm try checking the logs, should be something there now. Might be something related to redirecting to https infinitely, but hard to tell from the outside.

Comment: just checked the log viewer: **This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.**

Comment: That's pretty standard, anything else after that?

Comment: Also got an error: **Express in not a function**. Still trying to figure that out. That should be what is causing the 500 status error.

Comment: Did you ever get this one figured out? Any progress/new issues?

Comment: sadly no mate, since my site is just a site to show my knowledge of Reactjs to potential employers, I decided just to use static data in my Redux data store for now. I'm gonna accept I need to update my knowledge of hosting Nodejs apps on GCP

Comment: Oh I'm sorry to hear that, if you're still getting the "Express is not a function" message, it's likely due to something with your node modules, so maybe look into that as related to the GCP app engine